# Unable to Find Custom Notification Types ID

Tags: rest-api, process-builder, notification, summer19, push-notification

Even though my environment is in **api version 46.0**, custom notification types does not appear as in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customnotificationtype.htm#!).

The sObject does not pop up when queried via Workbench (same query as a recent [mothership article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/06/get-buildspiration-with-custom-notifications-in-summer-19.html)):

[image: SELECT id,CustomNotifTypeName FROM CustomNotificationType]

**However, I am able to create/send custom notifications through the process builder** (and only there).

Someone please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query CustomNotificationType in Tooling API, as the article suggests. In workbench you can do this by navigating to utilities->REST Explorer and then executing the following GET request:

/services/data/v46.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Id,CustomNotifTypeName+from+CustomNotificationType

Comment: it worked thank you so much!